# UIButton become nil when I open settings viewController

Tags: swift

I have map and zoom in/out button on it as strong outlet and settings viewController, where show/hide settings crash app because outlet button become nil. How to resolve this?

In mainViewController:

```
@IBOutlet var zoomIn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var zoomOut: UIButton!
...
```

and

```
func setZoomFalse(){
    zoomIn.isHidden = true
    zoomOut.isHidden = true
}

func setZoomTrue(){
    zoomIn.isHidden = false
    zoomOut.isHidden = false
}
```

SettingsViewController is open with:

```
self.present(self.settingsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

from slide menu

and this call make crash in settingsViewController:

```
@objc func switchChanged1(_ sender : UISwitch!){
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: settingsView.settingsIsZoom)

    isZoom = sender.isOn

    if isZoom {
        mainViewController.setZoomTrue()
    } else {
        mainViewController.setZoomFalse()
    }
}
```

Comment: You gotta show us some code.

Comment: Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this on this way, I set global variable to true in settingsViewController, which is defined as global in maonViewController, above class definition and in viewWillApear check if this variable is true and if yes I call setZoomTrue and it works on this way, when it's called from different viewController it crashes with nil message ...